# MySQL update column from other table

Tags: mysql

I've searched high and low and am stuck.

```
New table = p8dzk_jbusinessdirectory_companies | Column = comercialName
Old table = dir | Column = firm
```

I need eventually to move all data from old table to new table (most column names different) but ID and 'name' column records match.

I tried:

```
UPDATE p8dzk_jbusinessdirectory_companies JOIN dir ON p8dzk_jbusinessdirectory_companies.comercialName = dir.firm
SET dir.firm = p8dzk_jbusinessdirectory_companies.comercialName;

Result 0 rows affected.
```

Also tried renaming the old table column name to match the new one and ran the same query with edited column name - same result.

Help please?

Comment: Actually what you need is a INSERT INTO new (newcol1,newcol2) (SELECT oldCol1,oldCol2 FROM old)

Comment: Perhaps I need to clarify that there are already corresponding records in the new db table. Above insert statement added new records :( But, thank you for responding.

Comment: You are right. If you don't state your answer the right way then we can't help you the way you need

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem's solution, I tested with your query, I also got the same result.
Problem is that you are joining the table with comercialName and firm. your value will be inserted where both table's column will have same value. You are updating the same column where you have made condition of joining. You should choose another field to join the table and another field to update the value.
Let you have an example which I implemented to test.

```
UPDATE `test` join `tbl_salon_cont_no` on `test`.`emp_name`=`tbl_salon_cont_no`.`emp_name` SET `tbl_salon_cont_no`.`emp_name`=`test`.`emp_name`
```

here I got the same result what you got. Then Tried with another one and worked.

```
UPDATE `tbl_salon_cont_no` join `test` on `test`.`salon_id`=`tbl_salon_cont_no`.`salon_id` SET `tbl_salon_cont_no`.`emp_name`=`test`.`emp_name`
```

Here I got one rows affected.

```
----------------------------------
```

Finally you can not update the same value to same column, same row.

---

tbl_salon_cont_no:first image

test: second image

[image: tbl_salon_cont_no]

[image: test]

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance.. but could you repeat the working query with either table/column old/new or with my values? I'm completely lost as to what is what...

Comment: Have a look now. I have updated my answer. Do some changes to the value of fields and you'll see the result 1/2, etc. rows updated successfully.

Comment: Thank you so much! 
I still didn't get it, but I did end up finding something that did what I needed:
UPDATE new_table, old_table
SET    new_table.comercialName = old_table.firm
WHERE  new_table.name = old_table.name

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

UPDATE new_table, old_table SET new_table.comercialName = old_table.firm WHERE new_table.name = old_table.name